# Significant figures with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

Is there a possibility with pgfplots to print numbers with no decimals for the nodes?
By this, I mean printing '2' instead of '2.0e0'.

In my case, I want to remove the decimal part and add the percent sign, which would give'2%' instead of '2.0e0'.

--

Furthermore, how can I put the text node '1%' on the top of the corresponding bar ? (if the bar is negative, it won't be anymore on the top)

--

Here is a sample code and a picture which I want to improve.
[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
id a b  name
0 1.1 20 Name1
1 2.2 -10 Name2
2 3.3 15 Name3
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{data.dat}{\donnees}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar,xtick={0,1,2},xticklabels={a,b,c},point meta=explicit symbolic,nodes near coords=$\pgfplotspointmeta\%$]

\addplot table [x={id}, y={b},,meta expr=\thisrow{id}] {\donnees};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=0]{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%}` to format the numbers using PGF's very flexible number formatting macro. Note that you have to use `point meta=explicit` instead of `point meta=explicit symbolic` if your meta data is numeric, otherwise the number parser will fail.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
id a b  name
0 1.1 20 Name1
1 2.2 10 Name2
2 3.3 15 Name3
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{data.dat}{\donnees}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    xtick={0,1,2},
    xticklabels={a,b,c},
    point meta=explicit,
    nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=0]{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%}
    ]

\addplot table [x={id}, y={b},meta expr=\thisrow{id}] {\donnees};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I get '0%' for each bar, is there an error in the code ?

Comment: @user81566: I get the result shown in the screenshot when I compile my code. What version of PGFPlots are you using?

Comment: I have the version 1.7, which should be the latest version according to Miktex. Am I right ?

Comment: @user81566: The current version is 1.8, but I wouldn't have thought that there was a change between 1.7 and 1.8 that would affect this. When you copy my code into a new document, you get `0%`? Or only when you try to adapt this for your own code?

Comment: There was a mistake in Miktex, the pgfplots version used was 1.8. Here is the result obtained when compiling your code : http://i.stack.imgur.com/fMTPs.jpg

Comment: @Jake I also get `0%` and I think `\pgfplotspointmeta` should be used instead of `\pgfmathresult`.

Comment: @percusse: Oh yeah, you're right about the `\pgfplotspointmeta`. Does that fix the problem with the `0%` for you?

Comment: Yes but I get 0,1,2 percent somehow. Not 500,1000 as you have. Oops picture is changed nevermind :)